# Problem with special characters in flask python

Tags: python, flask

I'ven followed  [this](https://codeburst.io/building-your-first-chat-application-using-flask-in-7-minutes-f98de4adfa5d) tutorial and got a running server for chatting, but I still have a problem:

**It doesn't admit text with spanish accents or ñ , á, é, ó, ...**

Does someone knows what to add to code to get special characters work?

[image: imagen de muestra]

I tried to change the second line from html template from `<html lang="en">` to `<html lang="es">` but didnt' work. ¿Should I pass to utf8 every text enrty or create a dictionary to convert the string of characters to correct character?

This is the code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO    
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'vnkdjnfjknfl1232#'
socketio = SocketIO(app)    
@app.route('/')
def sessions():
    return render_template('session.html')    
def messageReceived(methods=['GET', 'POST']):
    print('message was received!!!')

@socketio.on('my event')
def handle_my_custom_event(json, methods=['GET', 'POST']):
    print('received my event: ' + str(json))
    socketio.emit('my response', json, callback=messageReceived)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, debug=True,host='0.0.0.0', port=1234)
```

y el archivo plantilla que carga es

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="es">
  <head>
    <title>Flask_Chat_App</title>
  </head>
  <body>

<h3 style='color: #ccc;font-size: 30px;'>Bienvenidos..</h3>
<div class="message_holder"></div>

<form action="" method="POST">
  <input type="text" class="username" placeholder="Nombre"/>
  <input type="text" class="message" placeholder="Mensaje"/>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.7.3/socket.io.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);
  socket.on( 'connect', function() {
    socket.emit( 'my event', {
      data: 'User Connected'
    } )
    var form = $( 'form' ).on( 'submit', function( e ) {
      e.preventDefault()
      let user_name = $( 'input.username' ).val()
      let user_input = $( 'input.message' ).val()
      socket.emit( 'my event', {
        user_name : user_name,
        message : user_input
      } )
      $( 'input.message' ).val( '' ).focus()
    } )
  } )
  socket.on( 'my response', function( msg ) {
    console.log( msg )
    if( typeof msg.user_name !== 'undefined' ) {
      $( 'h3' ).remove()
      $( 'div.message_holder' ).append( '<div><b style="color: #000">'+msg.user_name+'</b> '+msg.message+'</div>' )
    }
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is not with the content language, but with the content encoding. Make sure you use UTF-8 for your code and template files and fill free to add `<meta charset="utf-8" />` tag right after your opening `<html>` tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    ...
```

Comment: That sentence allows me to set titles with `ñ,á,é,..` but not to messages sended trough application. I think that somethink is missing in `<form action="" method="POST">
  <input type="text" class="username" placeholder="Nombre"/>
  <input type="text" class="message" placeholder="Mensaje"/>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>`

Comment: Your Python source code should be encoded using UTF-8 as well. Also check out the encoding of the data in a database (if you use one).